# Depopulating combo box when selecting a different item

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm having trouble clearing a combo box without the use of a button.

I'm attempting to populate a drop down combo box dependent upon which item a user selects. I.E if user clicks North East, another combo box gives the options to select New York or Massachusetts.

My problem occurs when selecting a different option in a combo box that has already had an event occur. For example if the user wants to go back and click South East instead of North East, instead of clearing the previous options the combo box just populates adds the new cities to the combo box.

I can't figure out how to clear the previous ones without using a clear button, but using one is not an option.

```
    If comboRegionBox.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        strRegion = comboRegionBox.Items(comboRegionBox.SelectedIndex)
        txtBoxRegion.Text = strRegion
    End If

    If comboRegionBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        With comboStateBox.Items
            .Add("New York")
            .Add("Massachusetts")
        End With
    End If

    If comboStateBox.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        strState = comboStateBox.Items(comboStateBox.SelectedIndex)
        txtBoxState.Text = strState
    End If

    If comboStateBox.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        With comboCityBox.Items
            .Add("New York City")
            .Add("Rochester")
        End With
    End If

    If comboStateBox.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        With comboCityBox.Items
            .Add("Boston")
            .Add("Concord")
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: @jmcilhinney Please post your above comments as an answer to this question, as they do in fact answer the question and are not asking for clarification.

Comment: @KeithStein, fair call.  I considered them more guidance as I wrote them rather than a solution but, looking back, there is probably enough specific information there to warrant an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any code there to remove items, so why would items be removed? If you want to remove a single item then you call `Items.Remove`, just as you call `Items.Add` to add a single item. If you want to remove all items then you call `Items.Clear`.

You shouldn't have all those `If` statements together. You should be handling the appropriate events and taking the appropriate actions. A `Button` simply raises a `Click` event for you to handle. Anything that you can do in that event handler, you can do in any other event handler, e.g. the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler of a `ComboBox`.

What you should be doing is handling the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `comboRegionBox` and clearing/populating `comboStateBox` in the event handler, then handling the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `comboStateBox` and clearing/repopulating `comboCityBox`.

Better still, use a `DataSet` with three `DataTables` and two `DataRelations` between them, bound to `BindingSources`, which are bound to the `ComboBoxes`. After setting up the data-binding, all the filtering will be done automatically, with no code required from you. Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?518065) out.